# Confusing Statement

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. There are seven tiles. Place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged to solve the corresponding clue.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answers are:

> State: ILLINOIS
>  Not a state: NO LIQUID
>  Betrayed a state: [QUISLING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidkun_Quisling)

Filled-in diagram:

> [image: Filled-in Venn diagram]

Comment: I don't really understand the "not a state" answer. I thought of it as a possibility, but it doesn't seem any more compelling to me than alternatives such as "ILLIQUID" and "NO IDLING"

Comment: Actually this is MY bad - I should have specified that the answers were eight letter words - I was looking for ILLIQUID - but then again I ironically did not state the rules correctly! - so happy that this one is correct

Comment: I don’t think I ever would have found the answer to “Betrayed a State.” Great work!